# Replacing a character if not preceeded by backslash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, backslash

Assume that you have in PHP a string

```
$string = 'Hello \world, how a\re you?';
```

I would like to replace all w and r if they are not preceeded by a backslash. I assume preg_replace is the way to go, but I do not understand enough of regex to make this work:

> $newString = preg_replace(array('/????/', '/????/'), array('!', '!'), $string);

If it works as I would like, the output should be

> echo $newString; // output: 'Hello \wo!ld, ho! a\re you?'

Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use negative look-behind:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)[wr]/', '!', $string);
```

Comment: In php, it's recommended to use **4** backslashes

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was easy if you actually rule regex. But I could not find such an example yet in the internet. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
/(?<!\\)[wr]/
```

As in the code:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)[wr]/', '!', $string);
```

Comment: In php, it's recommended to use **4** backslashes

Comment: @HamZa yes, when posting a regex pattern prefer to only escape the *pattern* as needed, and to exclude any other escaping required by the language.